# Laravel Multi Auth set up issue

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have installed Multi Auth following instructions by ollieread at https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth, but i'm missing some point here.

I got this error when running my app before replacing the configuration for auth (config/auth.php):

> ErrorException
>   Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver(), called in     /private/var/www/portal-varejo/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php     on line 81 and defined

Im pretty sure that whats missing is this (from documentation):

> Custom Auth Drivers
>
> At this current moment in time, custom Auth drivers written for the base Auth class will not >work. I'm currently looking into this particular issue but for the meantime, you can work >around this by changing your closure to return an instance of Ollieread\Multiauth\Guard >instead of the default.

How can i do that? What closure i'm supposed to change?

Running Laravel 4.1 here.

Comment: Could you show your configuration file code please, and are you using a custom driver?

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment out `'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider'` and `'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider'` from `app/config/app.php`.